# Where does Destiny 2 save screenshots?

Tags: pc, destiny-2

In the [Destiny 2 update 2.1.0](https://www.bungie.net/en/Explore/Detail/News/47462), released in Season 5, a screenshot key has been added.

> PC
>   Controls
>   Added new "Take Screenshot" keybind (defaults to the "Print Screen" key)

However the patch notes do not make mention of where these screenshots are saved.

Where are the images being saved?

Comment: There are few common locations [here](https://us.battle.net/support/en/article/28230) but I don't have the game installed to check if it is any of those.

Comment: Worth nothing that I had to manually bind the PrintScrn key in the options before this would work.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Testing this myself, Destiny 2 saves screenshots here:

`%AppData%\Bungie\DestinyPC\screenshots`

Comment: For lazy users like myself that should be able to be shortened to `%AppData%\Roaming\Bungie\DestinyPC\screenshots`

Comment: @TheLethalCroft Thanks! Your path works better, since there's a possibility that a user has relocated their AppData folder.

Comment: Minor: `%AppData%` may already point to the Roaming, as it seems to with current Windows 10 installs.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out @JuliaMcGuigan. I've made an edit to my answer to account for this.

Answer (score 1):

Win + R

Paste without quotes:
"%AppData%\Bungie\DestinyPC\screenshots"